# Non-readable POM /Users/sydneyfrancis/.m2/repository/org/apache/apache/27/apache-27.pom: i

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

```
/Users/sydneyfrancis/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.0.17/Contents/Home/bin/java "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/Users/sydneyfrancis/IdeaProjects/Trial " -Dmaven.home=/Users/sydneyfrancis/.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin/1ks0nkde5v1pk9vtc31i9d0lcd/apache-maven-3.8.6 -Dclassworlds.conf=/Users/sydneyfrancis/.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin/1ks0nkde5v1pk9vtc31i9d0lcd/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin/m2.conf "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=49569:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/sydneyfrancis/.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin/1ks0nkde5v1pk9vtc31i9d0lcd/apache-maven-3.8.6/boot/plexus-classworlds.license:/Users/sydneyfrancis/.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin/1ks0nkde5v1pk9vtc31i9d0lcd/apache-maven-3.8.6/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2020.2.4 verify
\[INFO\] Scanning for projects...
\[INFO\]
\[INFO\] -------------------------\< com.example:Trial \>--------------------------
\[INFO\] Building Trial 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
\[INFO\] --------------------------------\[ jar \]---------------------------------
\[WARNING\] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:3.3.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
\[INFO\] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\[INFO\] BUILD FAILURE
\[INFO\] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\[INFO\] Total time:  0.310 s
\[INFO\] Finished at: 2023-01-14T18:19:06+05:30
\[INFO\] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\[ERROR\] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:3.3.0: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.3.0
\[ERROR\] \[FATAL\] Non-readable POM /Users/sydneyfrancis/.m2/repository/org/apache/apache/27/apache-27.pom: input contained no data @ /Users/sydneyfrancis/.m2/repository/org/apache/apache/27/apache-27.pom
\[ERROR\] -\> \[Help 1\]
\[ERROR\]
\[ERROR\] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
\[ERROR\] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
\[ERROR\]
\[ERROR\] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
\[ERROR\] \[Help 1\] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I generated Springstarter and created a project on it. Java file.is not runnable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try to delete this dependency from `/Users/sydneyfrancis/.m2/repository` and reload from the command line outside of IntelliJ via Maven